# How to return large String byte and display in angularjs image RestController?

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, spring-boot

I am facing a problem while returning a string. I have a java code and which will convert to image. I am able to convert the image in the backend using this Java code but i need to do this in frontend.

```
String responseString="ë!!ëh$þë.ë
 (-0mÓæEÈRjqY-ÖÉr-Êjê×ªl-d@i¶`é¥­­mÛzàMÄínþÎmÝÞmÞ®ßþmàná&­&nÓ:mãêëã^írLî6ví^î³fî&r®Ù~®Â®ÛÜBìéöfêâ­Þ:@ëö-à
¸o¿ú¨üÒ¯ýf"æïðò/þoè¬­ { 0+0;0_ÆÌTðø6øïktðS§0 K®  o#
$ð[@?0t¬È'YpÓño0± íò8ø¥¥ÄFðd¾ÞFBùÁ¸éû&k%Jb<±hÁåJ?¤?| y®0Æp Ó0ãÀlÀÀXAðÿÀÿìðS°ñzÂ±÷T? "×<óq   ÿ1ò
ærhíû-×ïMèr®pTdEþkÎÀµÎ´ó #< Ø     ¬´A=?³?às>»Xó@ôA«©dRøCCoÀC8ßDEFórlôØÊGÓáHÿÁÚ4tJ¯4 ´ôKCóO3XÐ´M.Atâêô¤*4C;4Dï.B5
_ô×f´(õæ2µâSGµ$O5J«4K»´3k5rMsdXçôt
´Ëô@@
0VPÀûûû<ü     æü´öÀf(æoAFVüÅ?@
Dhp!C¹f¼Ø5"þÇ%ymÊ-cÂIÓfN<}JÔ(R¥LBJÕêÕ¬
8ÚÂ
-Ë&û"øðxáÍ`rÂ¨&2Ðá ¾xüI-bP`þ£ôJÈà@A&î è øÀèpÂ»2ã*òAÃÉ:ü0  I4 Ud aÆfÀQG}L
:î!a  O¸?þ±pD.ü;Ç¢¢¯p7à+xArnA!HèòÀý#X¼ hV"



String fileName = "one.gif";
 String fileLocation = new File("src\\main\\resources\\static\\img").getAbsolutePath() + "\\" + fileName;
      FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(fileLocation);
 fos.write(responseString.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"));
   fos.flush();
   fos.close();
```

I want to return this responseString and use in angularJs. How to return form Restcontroller and use in Angular/HTML? When I return directly responseString I am getting 
ERRORError: [$http:baddata] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.4/$http/baddata? also.

Answer (score 0):

**From the AngularJS docs:** "To resolve this error, make sure you pass valid JSON data to transformResponse or use an appropriate Content-Type header for non-JSON data."

Set the appropriate content-type header on the server side.

You should choose the appropriate MIME type from this list: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types